# CSS menubar ul li

Tags: css

Hi guys i'm trying to learn css ul and li menu bar. i'm trying to create this design http://s13.postimg.org/5bz1a4kw7/divider.jpg having the spaces and the divider per each menu bar, i can't seem to get the spacing, i tried adjusting it, but i can't get a grip on how to have this spacing per menu bar (li). Can you please get me to the right direction? Thanks

here's what i've done so far
http://jsfiddle.net/blackknights/Wbfjg/

```
<ul id="mcolor">
    <li><a href="default.asp"><font color="#000000"> Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have updated your code.

```
li a{
   display:block;
   padding:5px 10px;
   background:#ccc;
   border-right:1px solid #fff;
}
li a.last{
   border-right:none; 
}
```

Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wbfjg/4/)

Comment: how do i highlight the whole Home bar background  whenever i hover, without using float? can you please take a look at my code thanks http://jsfiddle.net/blackknights/6vCsA/1/

Comment: is there a way to do it Without Using FLOAT?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wbfjg/8/). Basically, make use of `padding-left` and `padding-right` and `min-width` for `li` elements.

Comment: is there a way to highlight to whole Home bar with yellow? like on this image? 
i tried adjusting the padding but i'm still not getting a hover result like this? http://postimg.org/image/cqeps1o2j/625db9d4/ 
THis is what i have so far http://jsfiddle.net/blackknights/6vCsA/1/